# Barcode font EAN 13 IDAutomationSUPCEANM.otf shows "DEMO" on right corner of the barcode

Tags: vba

[image: Barcode sample]

Barcode font, EAN 13 IDAutomationSUPCEANM.otf , shows "DEMO" on right corner of the barcode.

What is the right font? I use thermal printer to print barcode,
and my barcode length will be always 13. I had tried many barcode fonts, but IDAutomation was able to decrypt the barcode script.

Answer (score 0):

It's a demo font. Either use a licensed version or get your credit card out.